# Error While Working With Files

Tags: c

I'm trying to work on files in C. When I input a file name by command line it works but when I try and input the file name on the standard input it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
int main()
 {
  FILE * input;
  char  fileName[100];
  printf("Enter file name\n");
  scanf("%c",fileName);
  input=fopen(fileName,"r");
  readData(input);
  return 0;
 }
```

I run this code by this-

```
gcc temp.c -o exe
./exe
Enter file Name
input.txt
```

This give this error:

```
File not found or unable to read
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But this works:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
 {
  FILE * input;

  input=fopen(argv[1],"r");
  readData(input);
  return 0;
 }
```

I run this code like this:

```
gcc temp.c -o exe
/exe input.txt
```

Why is the first one giving an error?

Comment: `scanf("%c",fileName);` --> `scanf("%99s",fileName);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice this line

```
scanf("%c", fileName);
```

`%c` format string only accepts a **single** character. To read a whole string, use `%s` format string.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%c",fileName);` reads 1 `char` and saves that into `fileaName`.  At this point, `fileaName` is just an array of `char` with its first `char` initialized.  It is not a *string*:  an array of `char` up to and including the terminating `'\0'`.

`fopen(fileName,"r");` expected a string in `fileName`, yet that variable was not properly filled.  Thus the error "File not found or unable to read
Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Use `scanf("%99s",fileName);`

This will 1) skip leading white-space like `' '` and then 2) save up to 99 non-white-space `char` into `fileName`, finally appending `'\0'`.  The 99 is important as not to overfill `fileName[100]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
scanf("%c",fileName);
```

you try read single charcter. try

```
scanf("%s",fileName);
```

Also initialize your array with nulls

```
char  fileName[100] = {0};
```